# RAR is 3x larger than its content

Tags: rar

I've downloaded a couple of RAR files and noticed something very strange:

- File1.rar: 1.94GB

  - Video1.TS: 1.92GB
  - Readme.rtf: 1KB

- File2.rar: 1.94GB

  - Video2.MP4: 627MB
  - Readme.rtf: 1KB

`File2.rar` is *supposed* to contain `Video2.TS`, an HD video file, but it mistakenly contains `Video2.MP4`, a lower resolution version of the same video.

The thing that is totally baffling me though is that the compressed .rar file is 1.94GB, the size that it *would have been* if it contained the HD video, but its contents are only 627MB.  There are no hidden files, nothing weird about it (apart from the obvious.)

So the question is, *how is this even possible*?

Comment: i don't have rar on this machine but if i put the extracted contents into a .tar it's 627MB.

Comment: yep. video plays fine. no sign of corrupt files. i'm totally puzzled XD

Answer (score 2):

Without having access to the RAR file, it's impossible to know what's happening. There are two possibilities I can think of right now:

- The archive actually contains more files, but the headers got corrupted somehow, so he other files do not appear.
- The file size got (intentionally) by appending garbage data to the end of it. In the absense of the appropriate headers, appended data gets simply ignored.

Comment: Or appending not-garbage data--a hidden means of transmission